# Working with AFP in Objective-C/Carbon

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon, afp

I'm working on an app that needs to transfer files to an AFP volume -- ideally, it wouldn't mount the volume on OSX, since it's really unnecessary.

Looking over the AFP protocol stuff, I came across an old Carbon header file "afpDatastream.h".  This used to be in the framework "AppleShareClientCore", however it's no longer there (on Leopard anyway).

Assuming this has been deprecated, does anyone know what it was replaced with?

If not, do you know the best way to work with AFP volumes in Objective-C/Carbon transparently (not mounting in OSX)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple [*really*](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SystemFrameworks/SystemFrameworks.html) don't want anyone to use the AppleShare frameworks. Don't expect them all to be available in Snow Leopard.

Unfortunately, this means if you really want to avoid using the built-in mounting capabilities, you'll have to implement AFP yourself, or find some 3rd party code. [afpfs-ng](http://sourceforge.net/projects/afpfs-ng/) looks like a promising source of usable code, although it's GPL and would require work to turn into a library.

I would recommend just mounting the volumes - you can do this in such a way that they do not appear on the users's desktop, so they would not even notice ;-)